# Why doesn't None put in variable?

Tags: python, django

Why doesn't None put in variable?
I wrote in code like

```
def check(request):
    if len(request.POST.get('access_key')) >= 25:
        return HttpResponse('<h1>Hello</h1>')
    elif request.POST.get('access_key', None) == None:
        id_json = {}
        return JsonResponse(id_json, safe=False)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('<h1>Good</h1>')
```

Now I put anything to access_key in POSTMAN like
[image]

I think in this case the program goes into `elif request.POST.get('access_key', None) == None:`,but now it goes into `else:`.

I really cannot understand why the null value is not recognized as `None`. I wrote `print(type(request.POST.get('access_key')))` and blank is printed out.

I wanna make a system if no value is put, and the program should go into  `elif request.POST.get('access_key', None) == None:`.

How should I fix this?

Comment: Also, you should use `is` or `is not` when checking for `None`, not `==`/`!=`. `if x is None` or `if x is not None`

Comment: `print(None)` wouldn't print a blank. Ergo, you the value is not equal to `None`. Just use `elif not request.POST.get('access_key'):`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `request.POST.get('access_key')` is `''`, which is not `None`.

Try to check for `elif not request.POST.get('foo')`, this will catch both cases, because both, `` and None will evaluate to `False`.
Actually, all three values (`''`, `None`, and `False`) as `value` will fulfill the `if` condition `if not value:`.

Have a look at this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_string

> In most programming languages, the empty string is distinct from a null reference (or null pointer) because a null reference does not point to any string at all..

And more precisely for Python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html

> The sole value of `types.NoneType`. `None` is frequently used to represent the absence of a value, as when default arguments are not passed to a function.

Comment: However it is important to note that both `''` and `None` evaluate to `False` in an `if` condition (ie when passed to `bool`) https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/1453822

Comment: The default value for the second argument to `.get()` is already `None`. `elif not request.POST.get('foo'):` suffices.

Answer (score 1):

your `request.POST.get('access_key')` is equal `''`

so instead of

```
elif request.POST.get('access_key', None) == None:
```

try simple

```
elif not request.POST.get('access_key'):
```